# Check if class already assigned before adding

Tags: jquery, addclass

In jQuery, is it recommended to check if a class is already assigned to an element before adding that class? Will it even have any effect at all?

For example:

```
<label class='foo'>bar</label>
```

When in doubt if class `baz` has already been assigned to `label`, would this be the best approach:

```
var class = 'baz';
if (!$('label').hasClass(class)) {
  $('label').addClass(class);
}
```

or would this be enough:

```
$('label').addClass('baz');
```

Comment: I used `.hasClass` only when I need to check if class exists, if I just need to assign class - I use `.addClass`. jQuery doesn't duplicate the classes

Comment: Just add the class without testing. If it already exists, it won't be added again.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Just call `addClass()`. jQuery will do the check for you.  If you check on your own, you are doubling the work, since jQuery will *still* run the check for you.

Answer (score 48):

A simple check in the console would have told you that calling `addClass` multiple times with the same class is safe.

Specifically you can find the check in [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L62)

```
if ( !~setClass.indexOf( " " + classNames[ c ] + " " ) ) {
  setClass += classNames[ c ] + " ";
}
```

Comment: Please re-read my question and you will notice that its not about beeing safe but about best practice

Comment: From your edited answer I see that jQuery actually check if the class allready is assigned before adding it, i.e. it would be bad practice to do the check yourself / thanks

Comment: @Muleskinner that's what I was implying.

Comment: @Raynos:
**A simple check in the console would have told you that calling addClass multiple times with the same class is safe.**
Still, this question was one of the top hits when I Googled for an answer... Even trivial stuff that is well documented elsewhere has imho a place on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is OK, but really too complicated and not needed at all. The other answer should've been accepted.

Comment: There's far too much attitude in this answer. Could have answered it with some tact.

Comment: @Raynos **A simple check in the console** !== **documentation** by any measure. It may vary from browser to browser. However, **the source** is a much better option to rely upon. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 5):

This question got my attention following [another which was marked as a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181973/which-is-performancewise-better-check-for-class-or-add-class).

This answer summarises the accepted answer with a little added detail.

You're trying to optimise by avoiding an unnecessary check, in this regard here are factors you must be aware of:

1. it's not possible to have duplicate class names in the class attribute by means of manipulating a DOM element via JavaScript. If you have `class="collapse"` in your HTML, calling `Element.classList.add("collapse");` will not add an additional ***collapse*** class. I don't know the underlying implementation, but I suppose it should be good enough.
2. JQuery makes some necessary checks in its `addClass` and `removeClass` implementations (I checked the [**source code**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js)). For `addClass`, after making some checks and if a class exists JQuery doesn't try to add it again. Similarly for `removeClass`, JQuery does somethings along the line of `cur.replace( " " + clazz + " ", " " );` which will remove a class only if it exists.

Worth noting, JQuery does some optimisation in its `removeClass` implementation in order to avoid a pointless re-rendering. It goes like this

```
...
// only assign if different to avoid unneeded rendering.
finalValue = value ? jQuery.trim( cur ) : "";
if ( elem.className !== finalValue ) {
    elem.className = finalValue;
}
...
```

So the best *micro* optimisation you could do would be with the aim of avoiding function call overheads and the associated implementation checks.

Say you want to toggle a class named `collapse`, if you are totally in control of when the class is added or removed, and if the `collapse` class is initially absent, then you may optimise as follows:

```
$(document).on("scroll", (function () {
    // hold state with this field
    var collapsed = false;

    return function () {
        var scrollTop, shouldCollapse;

        scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        shouldCollapse = scrollTop > 50;

        if (shouldCollapse && !collapsed) {
            $("nav .branding").addClass("collapse");
            collapsed = true;

            return;
        }

        if (!shouldCollapse && collapsed) {
            $("nav .branding").removeClass("collapse");
            collapsed = false;
        }
    };
})());
```

As an aside, if you're toggling a class due to changes in scroll position, you are highly recommended to [throttle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) the scroll event handling.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("label")
  .not(".foo")
  .addClass("foo");
```