# jQuery add class to element, if this class is not already there

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it any **native** function in **jQuery** which check for class in an element, and then add it if this class does not exist yet?

Comment: Use `addClass()`. Or `toggleClass` if you want to remove class if already existing.

Comment: "native function in jquery" ? What does that mean ?

Comment: This question is way too basic. Just googling "add class jquery" is the way to go, not asking SO.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/2430414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call addClass(). jQuery will do the check for you. If you check on your own, you are doubling the work, since jQuery will still run the check for you.

source:
[Check if class already assigned before adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403472/check-if-class-already-assigned-before-adding)